# SCons to generate variable number of targets

Tags: python, code-generation, scons

I am trying to get `SCons` to generate multiple targets (number unknown directly in `SConscript`).

I have directory like:

```
headers/
  Header1.h
  Header2.h
  Header3.h
  Header4.h
meta/
  headers_list.txt
```

Now I want SConscript to read `headers_list.txt`, basing on its contents pick files from `headers/` directory (i.e. it might contain only `Header1` and `Header3`), for each of those I want to generate source using some function.

I have been trying to use `env.Command` to do that, but the issue is that it requires caller to specify targets list which for obvious reasons is not known when invoking `env.Command`.

The only thing I can think of is running:

```
for header in parse( headers_file ):
    source = mangle_source_name_for_header( header )
    env.Command( source, header, generator_action )
```

But this means I will be running `parse( headers_file )` each time I invoke `scons`.
If parsing is costly and the file is not often changed this step could be easily cached.

What SConsc construct/class/technique I am missing to achieve that caching?

**edit:**

It seems my question is similar to [Build-time determination of SCons targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870092/build-time-determination-of-scons-targets), but isn't there a technique without artificial dummy file?

Also, even with temporary file, I don't see how I am supposed to pass `target` variable from `Command` that generates variable number of targets to second one that would iterate over them.

**edit 2:**

[This](http://www.scons.org/wiki/DynamicSourceGenerator) looks promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found I can do it is with `emitter`.
Below example consists of 3 files:

```
./
|-SConstruct
|-src/
| |-SConscript
| |-source.txt
|-build/
```

**`SConstruct`**

```
env = Environment()

dirname = 'build'
VariantDir(dirname, 'src', duplicate=0)

Export('env')

SConscript(dirname+'/SConscript')
```

**`src/SConscript`**

```
Import('env')

def my_emitter( env, target, source ):
    data = str(source[0])
    target = []
    with open( data, 'r' ) as lines:
        for line in lines:
           line = line.strip()
           name, contents = line.split(' ', 1)
           if not name: continue

           generated_source  = env.Command( name, [], 'echo "{0}" > $TARGET'.format(contents) )
           source.extend( generated_source )
           target.append( name+'.c' )

    return target, source

def my_action( env, target, source ):
    for t,s in zip(target, source[1:]):
        with open(t.abspath, 'w') as tf:
            with open(s.abspath, 'r') as sf:
                tf.write( sf.read() )

SourcesGenerator = env.Builder( action = my_action, emitter = my_emitter )
generated_sources = SourcesGenerator( env, source = 'source.txt' )

lib = env.Library( 'functions', generated_sources )
```

**`src/source.txt`**

```
a int a(){}
b int b(){}
c int c(){}
d int d(){}
g int g(){}
```

**Output**:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
echo "int a(){}" > build/a
echo "int b(){}" > build/b
echo "int c(){}" > build/c
echo "int d(){}" > build/d
echo "int g(){}" > build/g
my_action(["build/a.c", "build/b.c", "build/c.c", "build/d.c", "build/g.c"], ["src/source.txt", "build/a", "build/b", "build/c", "build/d", "build/g"])
gcc -o build/a.o -c build/a.c
gcc -o build/b.o -c build/b.c
gcc -o build/c.o -c build/c.c
gcc -o build/d.o -c build/d.c
gcc -o build/g.o -c build/g.c
ar rc build/libfunctions.a build/a.o build/b.o build/c.o build/d.o build/g.o
ranlib build/libfunctions.a
scons: done building targets.
```

Also this has one thing I don't really like, which is parsing of `headers_list.txt` with each `scons` execution. I feel like there should be a way to parse it only if the file changed. I could cache it by hand, but I still hope there is some trick to make SCons handle that caching for me.

And I couldn't find a way to not duplicate files (`a` and `a.c` being the same).
One way would be to simply generate library in my_action instead of sources (which is approach I used in my final solution).