# SCons: how to add cpp files to source list

Tags: python, scons

In SCons, I have a pre-build step that generates an unknown number of files.  Once these files are generated, I need to be able to add the cpp files to my source list.  I am an absolute beginner at SCons, and I'm not sure what is the correct path to take.  What is the best method for doing this?

**Original:**
The basic/original build steps are as follows:

```
fpmFile = Dir('#').Dir('src').entry_abspath("FabricKINECT.fpm.json")
# The next step generates a bunch of source files
cppHeader = env.Command(
  [env.File(target + '.h')],
  klSources,
  [[kl2edkBin, fpmFile, "-o", hdir, "-c", cppdir]]
  )
env.Depends(cppSources, cppHeader)

# We pass in the supplied filelist to the build command
# however, this list does not include the cpp files generated above
# Currently I am hard-coding the generated files into
# the cppSources list, but I want to add them in dynamically
return env.SharedLibrary(
  '-'.join([target, buildOS, buildArch]),
  cppSources
  )
```

**What I've Tried**
I've tried several different angles:

http://www.scons.org/wiki/DynamicSourceGenerator, but from what I could figure out, this creates seperate build targets for each file, whereas I want them all to be included in my library build

Using an emitter: [SCons to generate variable number of targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953964/scons-to-generate-variable-number-of-targets), but I can't seem to get the dependency worked out - my scanner runs before anything else, no matter how I assign dependencies

I tried making another Command to gather a list of files -

```
def gatherGenCpp(target, source, env):
  allFiles = Glob('generated/cpp/*.cpp')
  # clear dummy target
  del target[:]
  for f in allFiles:
    target.append(f)

genSources = env.Command(['#dummy-file'], cppdir, gatherGenCpp)
env.Depends(genSources, cppSources)

allSources = genSources + cppSources
return env.SharedLibrary(
  '-'.join([target, buildOS, buildArch]),
  allSources
  )
```

This however fails with

> fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'dummy-file.obj'

I guess its because even though I clean the dummy-file entry out of the targets of the command, this happens after its registered with build system (and the expected targets are made.

all this to say - how would you implement the following:

- A command generates a bunch of CPP files
- These files are added to a passed in list of files
- We build a dll out of this list of cpp files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I simply ran an exec statement in scons to generate the files.  Sometimes, the shortest path is best :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell SCons that some files are generated using tool he doesn't know, use [Builders](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-writing).

I.e.:

```
env = DefaultEnvironment()

# Create a builder that uses sed to replace all of occurrences
# of `lion` word to `tiger`
BigCatBuilder = Builder(action = Action('sed "s/lion/tiger/g" $SOURCE > $TARGET'))
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'BigCatBuilder': BigCatBuilder})

# Create tiger.c from pre/lion.c
tiger_c = env.BigCatBuilder('tiger.c', 'pre/lion.c')

# tiger.c is globbed by Glob('*.c')
Program('tiger', Glob('*.c'))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - in my case, the action is not being called before the build step.  Also - is the job of the builder to supply the files to the build system, or is it just executing the 'generateFiles' step?  From what I can tell, its just the glob collecting files in this step.  If the build step hasn't run yet, then there are no files to collect.

Comment: @FrozenKiwi. You should note that calling `env.Command` as well as using builders doesn't directly invokes that command, it just tells SCons how to build targets ('tiger.c') if he has to. After evaluation of SConstruct it builds dependency tree (which can be dumped with `--tree=all`), and invokes commands according to previously built dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  The Glob will pick up the pre/lion.c file, and when it goes to build it it will call the BigCatBuilder builder.  The builder transforms the lion to tiger, and returns that to the build system.  If I passed in my fpm file to the Program call, then when it goes to build it it will trigger my builder, which will then generate all the cpp files.  I can then gather all the generated files and return them to the build system?

Comment: Not quite correct. `BigCatBuilder` is called explicitly, and it causes creation of `tiger.c` file, so SCons notes that and saves on its "virtual file system". When `Glob('*.c')` is called, it picks files from that "virt. file system" (`tiger.c`), so to build Program it needs first run your builder.

Comment: I cannot know before-hand what files will be generated, so I can't return them from the build step (at least, before the build step has run).

Comment: I only know for certain that one file will be generated, after the kl2edk binary has run I can gather and include the remaining files.

Comment: can I take the array returned from the buillder, and pass it into a Command which will add the extra files to it?

Answer (score 1):

As myaut correctly stated, the approach to use in your situation is to define a custom Builder. It should have your current Command string as Action, and then you'll probably also have to define a custom Emitter. See http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsForFools for a more detailed description of how to put all the "dots on the i".
The Emitter is important because it gets run while your build scripts are parsed, so when the env.BigCatBuilder is called. Its return value is the list of the targets that the actual Build step will produce (in the future). SCons stores these targets as Nodes in an internal structure, where it keeps track of information like: does this node have implicit dependencies?, is one of its children not up-to-date so the target needs a rebuild?...
The Glob() call will search in the local file system, but also traverses the mentioned "virtual file tree"...and, like this, is able to track dependencies to files that don't physically exist yet.
You don't have to manage lists of generated files and pass them around to the different Builders. Glob() usually does most of the work for you...

Comment: The problem is - I don't know what files are created until the build step has run.  I can't return the file created.

Comment: But the tool that creates your generated source file(s) does know, right? It's a deterministic process, meaning that with the same input you get exactly the same number of files (including same names and same content) as output. You have to figure out the underlying rules for this, and re-implement them in your Builder/Emitter. This is the correct path to take, and how all the more complicated SCons Tools basically work...for example the MOC support for Qt4/Qt5 or the SWIG Builder.

Comment: Ouch - the tools is meant to be an interop between 2 different languages.  To determine what files will be created would in many respects be the same as creating a lexical parser for the files.  Is there another way?  Can I pass in the output array of the builder to a command as an input and modify it there?  The array is passed by reference in python, so modifying there should modify it everywhere.  Or would scons not take kindly to me modifying the input list once its already running?  (I've spent a few hours trying to get that working already, so I guess the answer is... no)

Comment: Perhaps the best would be to just do a sys call out and execute the file generator instead of trying to run this through scons.  Once thats done I can just grab the file list and everything flows happily from there.

Comment: You could certainly do the latter, but then you aren't tracking dependencies anymore. Regarding the problems and implications of Builders/Emitters you might want to have a look at the threads https://pairlist4.pair.net/pipermail/scons-users/2014-December/003234.html and https://pairlist4.pair.net/pipermail/scons-users/2014-December/003245.html in our User mailing list. They kind of explain the underlying mechanisms in somewhat greater detail.